ntfs external hard drive does not mount
I was trying to copy a bunch of files from my father's 1TB SDD NTFS external hard drive to my Linux desktop. The computer froze and I couldn't do anything but move the mouse pointer. It wasn't something too unusual for me though, so I just plugged my PC off. I didn't think much of it and I turned the PC back on. When I tried mounting the hard drive, I got this pop-up:

I searched for solutions and here's everything I tried:
fdisk -l - /dev/sdb is the external hard disk
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.48 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Disk model: Elements 25A2   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C46C72EC-9300-4BC7-8B26-120E0312BFE7

Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 1953456127 1953454080 931.5G Microsoft basic data

dmesg - I can't use chdsk at the moment. also, I'm afraid that it might delete some files.
[ 2197.800226] ntfs3: sdb1: It is recommened to use chkdsk.
[ 2198.168774] ntfs3: sdb1: volume is dirty and "force" flag is not set!

sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb -n - I looked for a chdsk alternative and found ntfsfix. I used -n because I can't take any risk
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
No change made

Unrecoverable error

I really can't lose any data on this computer.

Does this answer your question? How to mount an external HDD?

@graham
tried the first solution,
output-
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 3).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.


Most common issue is Windows fast startup has set hibernation flag. Then the Linux NTFS driver will not fully mount the NTFS partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation
You may  be able to manually mount read only with ro parameter.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

I had what looks the be exactly this problem in Ubunbtu 24.04LTS with a Seagate 1tb U.S.B. external drive.  My solution was to open the 'Disks' program and select the "faulty" drive.  I then left clicked on the gear wheel and from the menu presented I selected the "Edit Mount Options" entry. This gave me a pop up screen entitled "Mount Options". First on this popup I turned off the user session defaults and at the bottom of the page I deleted the File System type "auto" and inserted "ntfs". after clicking on "OK" I clicked on the mount triangle and the disk then mounted.  To test this I disconnected the disk and unplugged it then reconnected and it mounted immediately by itself.

Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!
